# Reading string vector as date

Tags: r, string, date

Reading this string format "05MAR15:21:58:17" as a date in R

Comment: Is the 15 for the year 2015?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In base R:

```
x <- "05MAR15:21:58:17"
```

To extract the date one can use:

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(x, format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'))
#"2015-03-05"
```

and, similarly, for the time:

```
format(as.POSIXct(x, format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'),"%H:%M:%S")
[1] "21:58:17"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i tried them : 
`> x <- "05MAR15:21:58:17"

> as.Date(as.POSIXct(x, format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'))

[1] NA
> format(as.POSIXct(x, format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'),"%H:%M:%S")
[1] NA`
am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Re : 
I fixed the NA problem by 
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

They key is the `lubridate` package!

```
library(lubridate)
x="05MAR15:21:58:17"  
dmy_hms(x)
```

The `dmy_hms` stands for "day month year hours minutes seconds" which is the order they appear in your string. Similarly there is a `mdy_hms` function among others.